# Histogram normalised to area 1

Tags: histogram, normalization, area

i have a histogram with the y-axis showing the proportion in percentage. That makes sense to me but now i have read that histograms can be normalized with the result that the area of the rectangles is 1.

Can someone explain me the idea,reason behind this?
Many thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about stats (try http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all histograms are normalised.

For example, individuals by hair color:

- Blond 2 (Alex, Beckham)
- Gray 3 (Foo, Bar, Baz)
- ...

This histogram is not normalised, because individuals in result set are relevant.

Compare with repairs by car make:

- Fiat 81%
- Daewoo 18%
- Toyota 1%

This histogram is normalised to 100% because individual number of repairs is irrelevant.

Comment: I know that, thx ;) but i have seen many histograms where the area is 1. I was just wondering why? There must be a reason. I have the suspect the reason behind this is a better interpretation as one would be forced to use a certain bin width. Otherwise the area wont be 1. But i thought it would be nice to hear some other opinions from people with statistical knowledge :-)

Comment: `100%` == 100 per cent = 100/100 = `1.` numerical statistics typically range `0..1` where `1` is always.

Comment: no, i am not talking about the value of the y-axis. i mean the area of the rectangle in the histogram. if you calculate the area of the rectangles you get 1. thx for your effort :-)

Comment: oh do you mean to say that each data point is normalised to 1? as in some rectangles are wide and thin and others are short and thick?